# Use of relay in a gas sensor (safety issue)

Tags: relay, safety, smoke-sensor

I have developed an MQ-5 based LPG gas sensor which uses a relay.

Is the relay itself a fire hazard (while switching) if gas is in the vicinity ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if it's open to the atmosphere. Redesign with a reed relay.

Comment: Would the typical relay module (blue casing, 5VDC, 10A @ 250VAC) count as "open to the atmosphere" ?

Comment: Yes it probably would.

Comment: Could one use a solid-state relay, are these safe in a volatile gas environment ?

Answer (score 3):

There are relays that are made for use in hazardous locations such as one where explosive gases are present.  The term for these relays is **intrinsically safe** and they either operate on such low energy that they will not ignite flammable or explosive materials, or they are sealed in such a manner that the gasses (or explosive dust, etc.) are protected from the live parts.

There are **intrinsically safe barrier relays** which are interposing relays designed to operate at intrinsically safe levels on one side and normal levels on the other.

It's a broad and complex topic way beyond this answer, but hopefully those terms will provide you with a start for further research.

Answer (score 2):

Back when I still worked we sold instruments with control relays.  Hermetic relays were an option.
[image]